# Python webscraping not showing all rows with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing, html-parsing

Trying to scrape the squad overviews of several webpages from Transfermarkt and realised that for some pages rows were missing.

Here are two example webpages:

**Works**: All rows included [here](https://www.transfermarkt.com/fc-bayern-munich-u17/kader/verein/21058/saison_id/2018/plus/1).

**Doesn't work**: Rows missing [here](https://www.transfermarkt.com/grasshopper-club-zurich-u17/kader/verein/59526/saison_id/2018/plus/1)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
df_headers = ['position_number' , 'position_description' , 'name' , 'dob' , 'nationality' , 'height' , 'foot' , 'joined' , 'signed_from' , 'contract_until']
r = requests.get('https://www.transfermarkt.com/grasshopper-club-zurich-u17/kader/verein/59526/saison_id/2018/plus/1', headers = headers)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

position_number = [item.text for item in soup.select('.items .rn_nummer')]
position_description = [item.text for item in soup.select('.items td:not([class])')]
name = [item.text for item in soup.select('.hide-for-small .spielprofil_tooltip')]
dob = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(3):not([id])')]
nationality = ['/'.join([i['title'] for i in item.select('[title]')]) for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(4):not([id])')]
height = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(5):not([id])')]
foot = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(6):not([id])')]
joined = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(7):not([id])')]
signed_from = ['/'.join([item['title'].lstrip(': '), item['alt']])  for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(8):not([id]) [title]')]
contract_until = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(9):not([id])')]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(position_number, position_description, name, dob, nationality, height, foot, joined, signed_from, contract_until)), columns = df_headers)
print(df)

df.to_csv(r'Uljanas-MacBook-Air-2:~ uljanadufour$\grasshopper18.csv')
```

This is what I am getting for a page which should contain 22 rows.

```
  position_number  ... contract_until
0               -  ...              -
1               -  ...              -
2               -  ...              -
3               -  ...              -
4               -  ...              -
5               -  ...              -
6               -  ...              -
7               -  ...              -
8               -  ...     30.06.2019

[9 rows x 10 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I can't identify why it works for some and others it does not.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in variables. If one of variable has only 9 items but other variables have more items then `zip()` will create only 9 rows - it always uses  the shortes list to create data.

Comment: Yes I can see that the `signed from` variable seems to be the dependant variable in those cases. Is there a workaround to get an empty string instead of shortening the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this line:

```
signed_from = ['/'.join([item['title'].lstrip(': '), item['alt']])  for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(8):not([id]) [title]')]
```

and you can modify it this way:

```
signed_from = ['/'.join([item.find('img')['title'].lstrip(': '), item.find('img')['alt']])  if item.find('a') else '' for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(8):not([id])')]
```